# QML: How to access Listelements

Tags: listview, qml, components

I am new to QML and need some help.

I am filling a listview by python code.

Each list element consists of a checkbox and related text.
Additionally I want to use 2 Buttons to select/deselect all checkboxes at once. In the onClicked function of the buttons, I can access the itemName, but I am failing to access the checked state.

How can I solve this issue?

```
            Rectangle{
                
                ListModel {
                    id: sportItems
                }

                Component{
                    id:sportRow   
                    CheckBox{
                        text: "<font color=\"white\">"+itemName+"</font>"
                        checked: true
                        onClicked : {
                            console.log(itemName+" :::: "+ checked);
                        }
                    }
                }

                ListView{
                    id: sports
                    objectName: "sports"
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    anchors.leftMargin: 10
                    model: sportItems
                    delegate: sportRow

                    function addItem(entry){
                        sportItems.append({itemName: entry})
                        sports.height = sports.height+20
                    }
                }
                Row{
                    anchors.top: sports.bottom
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    
                    Button{
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        anchors.leftMargin: 10
                        text: "All"
                        onClicked: {
                            for(var x =0; x< sports.model.get(0).count; x++){
                                sports.model.get(x).checked = true
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    Button{
                        anchors.right: parent.right
                        anchors.rightMargin: 10
                        text: "Nothing"
                        onClicked: {
                            for(var x =0; x< sports.model.get(0).count; x++){
                                sports.model.get(x).checked = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You're trying to access `checked` from sports.model. Does your model have a role named "checked"? If so, your checkboxes are not reading from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to modify the checked state outside of your delegate (i.e. from the Check All button) then the checked state should really be a part of your model. So you can add a role named something like "isChecked" (so it doesn't conflict with the CheckBox's built-in `checked` property):

```js
function addItem(entry) {
    sportItems.append({ 
        itemName: entry, 
        isChecked: true    // Keep the checked state
    })
    sports.height = sports.height+20
}
```

Then make sure the delegates actually read/write that data from the model:

```js
Component {
    id:sportRow   
    CheckBox {
        text: "<font color=\"white\">"+itemName+"</font>"
        checked: isChecked   // Read from the model
        onClicked : {
            // Write back to the model
            sportItems.setProperty(index, "isChecked", !isChecked)
        }
    }
}
```

In your Check All button, you just need to set the model values:

```js
Button {
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 10
    text: "All"
    onClicked: {
        for(var i = 0; i < sports.model.count; i++) {
            sports.model.setProperty(i, "isChecked", true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The buttons itself work pretty well. Unfortunately, once I select/deselect one of the checkboxes manually, the buttons loose there functionality for this checkbox. Any hints?

Comment: What do you mean by "lose their functionality"? I tried it myself and they seem to continue functioning normally.

Comment: When I select or deselect the checkbox by mouse, it keeps that status, even if I press the All or Nothing button. For  all other checkboxes, it works fine.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior at all. It's working as expected for me when I run this code.

Comment: Long search, easy fix ;-)  Had a typo in the import. changed : import QtQuick.Controls 1.2 -> import QtQuick.Controls 2.2 did it.

Comment: Note that instead of `onClicked: sportItems.setProperty(index, "isChecked", !isChecked)` you can just do `onToggled: model.isChecked = checked`